# AWK - how to add the first line of the file?

Tags: awk, gawk

This command appends lines to the end of the file

> for i in $(ls); do awk 'BEGIN{print "last_line"}' >> "$i"; done

How to add lines to the beginning of the file? I tried so

> for i in $(ls); do awk 'NR==1{print "first_line" }'1 "$i" > "$i"; done

Comment: almost, `for i in $(ls); do awk 'NR==1{print "first_line" }'1 "$i" > tmp && mv tmp "$i"; done`

Comment: also could use for `i in *` to stop people crying about parsing ls

Answer (score 1):

the sed answer works. if you like awk:

```
awk 'NR==1{$0="first line"RS$0}7' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

you can put it within your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use sed instead

```
[rdarji@indlin091 Experiments]$ cat File2
This is line number: 2
This is line number: 3
This is line number: 4
This is line number: 5
[rdarji@indlin091 Experiments]$ sed -i '1i\
> This is line number: 1' File2
[rdarji@indlin091 Experiments]$ cat File2
This is line number: 1
This is line number: 2
This is line number: 3
This is line number: 4
This is line number: 5
```

Comment: How to do it in a loop for multiple files? for i in `ls`; do sed -i '1i\ > "$i"; done ?

Comment: First of all, you should never parse the output of ls which you just mentioned.
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

In case of a loop,
for j in {1..5}; do sed -i '$ji\
This is line number: $j' File2; done

Comment: And in case you need to edit every file from the folder like this then you can use find command like this:
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sed -i '1i\Line goes here' {} \;